# Android Here Paypal SDK Magnetic Swipe

Tags: android, paypal

Am Facing the below error while using the Paypal Here SDK magnetic swipe..!
**"Unexpected response code 500 for https://www.paypal.com/webapps/hereapi/merchant/v1/pay 05-22 10:55:16.231  16254-16254/com.paypal.heresdk.sampleapp E/PPHSDK﹕ HereTakePaymentRequest- RESPONSE BODY ON ERROR: {"correlationId":"fd71a84d42498","errorCode":580031,"message":"Please try another card","developerMessage":"This credit card cannot be processed by PayPal","errorType":"pay/bad_card"}"**

We are working one of our projects to US clients for integrating Paypal Here SDK.The problem am facing is while swipe the magnetic card reader into the sample application it shows the error. and unable to get the success response from the magnetic card reader response.

So kindly help me for proceed the next step.
Thanks in an advance!!